# How to save rolling files in a different directory?

Tags: java, log4j

In my project we are using log4j for logging purposes. We are using daily DailyRollingFileAppender and the problem is the file is rolled over each minute as expected. But we want to store the file in a different location. Below is my configuration.

```
<appender name="OUTPUT"
        class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="file" value="D:\\log\\selvaLog.log" />
        <param name="datePattern" value="yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm'.'" />
        <param name="append" value="true" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd:MM:yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} - %C{1} (%M:%L) - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

The above configuration creates file in below format:

```
D:\Log
            selvaLog.log
            selvaLog.log2017-12-18 15-28
            selvaLog.log2017-12-18 15-29
```

But what we wanted to store the file like this:

```
D:\Log
        selvaLog.log


D:\Log\Archived
        selvaLog.log2017-12-18 15-28
        selvaLog.log2017-12-18 15-29
```

Is it possible to store the rollover in different location, instead of the current directory?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For a use case like that, you will have to use a custom file appender where you build the archived file name from scratch and prefix the relative path to the different directory there.

e.g.:

`../Archieved/selvaLog.log.2017-12-18`

Check out the API for [FileAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/FileAppender.html)

Comment: These might help as well: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/logging/log4j/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/log4j/RollingFileAppender.java

Comment: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/logging/log4j/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.java